# define owner for my database

Tags: c#, sql-server, networking

How can I create owner for my database (that has been created with codes) owner with user guest?? I want to give access to my database to every client on local network. If I manually set guest it works true but I want with code do it.

My code is:

```
use test 
alter user[guest] login [guest] 
exec sp_addrolemember 'db_owner','guest';
```

I want to set the owner of my database to guest user that exist, but this code doesn't execute successfully. Where is my problem??

thanks.

Comment: Also: why do you think you need to make `guest` your db owner?? Just assign the permissions needed to the pre-defined `public` role in your database, and anyone logged in will be able to see and use your database...

Comment: The "public" role always exists - no need to pre-define anything. Just assign permissions to select on your tables or execute your stored procs to "public" (`GRANT SELECT ON dbo.YourTable TO public`) and you're done

Answer (score 0):

```
use test; 
alter user 'guest' WITH login='guest';
exec sp_addrolemember 'db_owner','guest';
GO;
```